# Goroutines are falling asleep

Tags: go, concurrency

I am getting **fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!**, even though I am using buffered channel and getting results too. But after getting all results I getting error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    StartJobExample()
}

var MAX_NUM = 1000
func StartJobExample(){
    t1 := time.Now()
    jobs := make(chan int,MAX_NUM)
    result:=make( chan int,MAX_NUM)

    go worker(jobs,result)
    writeNums(jobs)


    for j := range result{
        fmt.Println("number read is ",j)
    }
    close(result)

   t2 := time.Now()

   fmt.Println("Time taken in operation ",t2.Sub(t1).Seconds())
}

func  worker(jobs <-chan int ,result chan<- int){
         for i:= range jobs{
                result<-addTwo(i)
         }
}

func writeNums(jobs chan<- int){
    for i:=0;i<MAX_NUM;i++{
        fmt.Println("adding job ",i)
        jobs<-i
    }
    close(jobs)
}

func addTwo(i int)int{
    return i+2
}
```

Comment: `for j := range result` breaks out of the loop when the channel `result` is closed.  The channel `result` is closed after the loop. Deadlock.

Comment: You would do well to learn to use `gofmt`.

Comment: If i increase number of worker by adding `go worker(jobs,result) ` more than 1 time than Emin's solution is failing. can anyone please try it by increasing number of workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code, so let's go through them one by one.

First, you don't really need buffered channels in your case, as they are currently helping to mask your real problem.

Second, the `writeNums` function should be executed in a separate goroutine. Right now, you have writing in the `jobs` channel and reading from the `result` channel in the same goroutine (the `main` goroutine), which in your case is bound to produce a deadlock. This problem was masked by using buffered channels. So, just do:

```
go writeNums(jobs)
```

Third, your current code will never execute this:

```
for j := range result{
        fmt.Println("number read is ",j)
    }
    close(result)
```

This is what is producing a deadlock in your example. The `result` channel will never close because `close(result)` is executed after the `for` loop. You should put this `close(result)` in the `worker` function, after the `for` loop.

```
func  worker(jobs <-chan int ,result chan<- int){
         for i:= range jobs{
                result<-addTwo(i)
         }
         close(result)
}
```

This way, the `result` channel will close right after the `jobs` channel closes, and the `for` loop exits.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/rziIvrfh8ey) is a working example with unbuffered channels. You can modify it to include buffers, but it is working without it as well.

**EDIT:**

*Solution with multiple workers*

The main problem of adding more `worker` goroutines is closing the `result`. Since there are more `worker` goroutines in play now, all `worker` goroutines need to finish putting values into the `result` channel before the `result` channel can be closed.

This can be done with a sync mechanism like `sync.WaitGroup`. Here are the changes:

```
func StartJobExample(){
    t1 := time.Now()
    numberOfWorkers := 5
    jobs := make(chan int)
    result:=make( chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    //initialize a goroutine for syncing completion for all workers
    go func() {
      wg.Wait()
      close(result)
    }()
    
    //initialize all workers
    for i :=0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++ {
      wg.Add(1)
      go worker(&wg, jobs, result, i)
    }

// rest of the StartExample function is unchanged
// ...
}

func  worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, jobs <-chan int ,result chan<- int, num int){
    for i:= range jobs{
           result<-addTwo(i)
    }
    wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("closing worker ", num)
}
```

In this example, you use the `sync.WaitGroup` to sync all the `worker` goroutines. You start by adding a separate goroutine for waiting on all the `worker` goroutines to finish (`wg.Wait()`) and closing the `result` channel.

Second, before you create each `worker` goroutine, you need to do `wg.Add(1)` first.

Third, modify the `worker` function so it can execute `wg.Done()` after it is done reading from the `jobs` channel and writing to the `result` channel.

When the last `worker` goroutine executes `wg.Done()`, `wg.Wait()` will unblock the execution in its goroutine and execute `close(result)`. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/30O87H2ucuf) is a complete example of how it works.

Comment: `The result channel will never close because close(result) is executed after the for loop. You should put this close(result) in the worker function, after the for loop.` This is not exactly right. The program will never reach the statement `close(result)` because the program will block pushing into pushing into `jobs` which in turn will block because its drainer (`worker`) will block pushing into `results` because at that point of execution, its drainer is not yet working. More importantly, closing a channel signifies there will not be any further writes, and that reading over it can stop.

Comment: It is also a well known pattern that the routine responsible for writing a channel should be responsible to close it in order to prevent a panic about writing a closed channel.

Comment: If i increase number of worker by adding `go worker(jobs,result) ` more than 1 time than Emin's solution is failing. can anyone please try it by increasing number of workers.

Comment: @AditySingh you have never requested a solution with multiple workers in your question. Multiple `worker` goroutines require a different approach that includes sync mechanisms.

Comment: @mh-cbon sorry for not being clear, I was referring to the code example from the question. In this example, the `jobs` and `result` channels are buffered channels and the `jobs` channel won't block in this particular example. I've added a print statement in this example to show that `jobs` channel gets closed: https://play.golang.org/p/Aqf61CZ06lZ

Comment: yeah right. Kinda forgotten they were buffered.

Comment: i have reached to limit of asking question ,can anyone please help with the more number of workers.

Comment: The goroutine calling Wait must be scheduled after the Add calls, else the channel may be closed prematurely.

Comment: The link to the complete example shows that `writeNums` goroutine, which controls closing of the `jobs` channel, and therefore the execution of the `wg.Wait()` call, is executed after the Add calls. In this particular setup, the current code works fine, but I do agree that it should be done like that as a general rule.